Cannot get the TPROXY UDP to actually receive some data inside
I believe I am dealing with a routing issue on my system (which is a default Ubuntu 22 installation) but I really can't understand how to approach the debugging of said problem.
By following the Kernel's Transparent Proxy tutorial, I'm trying to implement a transparent proxy for all the outbound UDP traffic with destination port being 53 (that is, I'm trying to filter all the DNS requests on my system).
After many tutorials online, here's the setup that I think should work (but doesn't actually):
# iptables -t mangle -N DIVERT
# iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp -m socket -j DIVERT
# iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 1
# iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT
# ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
# ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
# iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port 5354

The C code for the actual UDP socket that waits for incoming traffic:
void intercept()
{
    int fd;
    ssize_t bytes_received_len;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    struct sockaddr_in inbound_addr, forward_server_addr;
    socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(inbound_addr);

    if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("inbound socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int val = 1;
    setsockopt(fd, SOL_IP, IP_TRANSPARENT, &val, sizeof(val));

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port = htons(5354);

    bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    for (;;)
    {
        printf("waiting on port 5354\n");

        bytes_received_len = recvfrom(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&inbound_addr, &addr_len);

        printf("received %zd bytes\n", bytes_received_len);

        if (bytes_received_len == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}

All the error handling is skipped for clarity.
As you can see from the iptables commands, I'm trying to outbound traffic to port 53 into my local proxy at 127.0.0.1: 5354. I never actually receive anything useful from recvfrom even if I actuall DNS requests on my system and they work, but they seem to bypass the proxy completely.
Am I missing anything super obvious?
I did look into all these articles:

Above mentioned kernel tutorial
This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738588/ip-transparent-usage
Even if it's about Rust, it was still useful: https://serverfault.com/questions/1143600/tproxy-is-not-redirecting-all-traffic-to-a-specified-port
go-tproxy: https://github.com/KatelynHaworth/go-tproxy

Any pointer would be super helpful. It really just feels like I'm missing something really obvious.

It's worth considering that a significant proportion of DNS traffic now goes over TCP rather than UDP, since signed DNS responses can be larger than typical MTUs.

In the end, TPROXY is now a good solution for this use case since it is not suitable for proxying traffic generated locally on the same machine with the proxy process.
A better way to solve this generally is implementing a Kernel module and using the netfilter API.

If you want to proxy local (not from external machines) traffic, you have to use OUTPUT instead of PREROUTING to process local packets, right?
And you don't need --tproxy-mark in this case.
Commands will be like
# iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j MARK --set-mark 1
# ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
# ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
# iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j TPROXY --on-port 5354

See my post on dev.to for detail.

Thank you. The approach with redirecting to the loopback is quite interesting. I haven't got to work it yet (no traffic received into my local proxy on port 5354) but I will keep playing with it, maybe I'll be able to do it.
For now I'm just doing it with NAT like this: iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m mark \! --mark 5 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:5354
This is less ideal (because it overrides packet destination) but gets the job done.
